# Proving that for each prime number $p$, the number $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, irrational-numbers, rationality-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$\sqrt a$ is either an integer or an irrational number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number)

I'm a total beginner and any help with this proof would be much appreciated. Not even sure where to begin.

> Prove that for each prime number $p$, the square root of p is irrational.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Have you seen any proofs of the fact that the square root of 2 is irrational? If so, try to generalize its ideas, and edit your post when you've got more questions.

Comment: If you're allowed to use the rational root theorem, consider the polynomial $x^2-p$...

Comment: This shouldn't be a duplicate. Proof is simpler in this case where $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sqrt p=\frac{a}{b}$  where (a,b)=1  and a>1 as p>1,

then $p=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$.

Now as p is integer, $b^2$ must divide $a^2$, which is impossible unless b=1 as (a,b)=1.

If b=1, p=$a^2$ which can not be prime as a>1.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\sqrt{p}=\frac{m}{n}$, where $m,n$ are relatively prime integers and $n\neq 0$. Then by squaring you get $n^2\cdot p=m^2$, so $p$ divides $m^2$. As $p$ is prime we must have $p^2$ divides $m^2$. On the other hand then $p^2$ divides $pn^2$ so $p$ divides $n$. Hence $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime so we reached a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ gcd(m,n)\!=\!1,\: \frac{m}n =\! \sqrt{p}\,\Rightarrow m^2\!=\!pn^2\!.\,$ Euclid's Lemma $\rm\Rightarrow m^2|\:p\,\Rightarrow m^2\! = 1= pn^2\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

**Remark** $\ $ This is a [key step](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/139743/242) employed in [one proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/140019/242)  of *uniqueness of squarefree decompositions*, of which $\rm\:m^2 \ne pn^2\:$ is a special case.

Comment: The proof is correct. The downvotes are quite puzzling. If you have questions then please feel welcome to ask.