# Direct proof that if p is prime, then $ \sqrt{p} $ is irrational.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Does anyone know of a simple direct proof that if p is prime, then $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational?

I have always seen this proved by contradiction and have been trying unsuccessfully to prove it constructively. I searched this site and could not find the question answered without using contradiction.

Comment: Since the definition of irrational is not rational, most proofs of irrationality are contradictions.

Comment: Tim Gowers has some [discussion here](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/when-is-proof-by-contradiction-necessary/) about how any such proof really must be by contradiction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that for each prime number $p$, the number $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176424/proving-that-for-each-prime-number-p-the-number-sqrtp-is-irrational)

Comment: OP--proofs not necessarly by contradiction can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number), which the duplicate was closed as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an *elementary* proof that I gave in a more general context, but I can't find it on the site, so I'll adapt it  to this case.

Set $n=\lfloor \sqrt p\rfloor$. Suppose $\sqrt p$ is rational and let $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $m\sqrt p$ is an integer. Consider $m'=m(\sqrt p-n)$; it is an integer, and
$$ m'\sqrt p=m(\sqrt p-n)\sqrt p=mp-nm\sqrt p  $$
is an integer too.

However, since $0\le \sqrt p-n <1$, we have $0\le m' <m $. Since $m$ is the *smallest* positive integer such that $ m\sqrt p$ is an integer, it implies $m'=0$, which means $\sqrt p=n$, hence $p=n^2$, which contradicts $p$ being prime.

Answer (score 0):

You could first prove that all square numbers have a prime decomposition with all primes of even powers.

For example if $k$ is square, and,

$k=\prod_{k=1}^{n}p_{k}^{e_{k}}$,

then each of $e_{k}$ must necessarily be even.

From there it is enough to show that primes have an odd power (namely 1) in their decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

For specific primes you can prove $x^2-p$ is irreducible over the rationals by proving it is irreducible modulo some other prime $q$. This means that $\sqrt{p}$ cannot be rational. This can probably be done in general using quadratic reciprocity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Rational Root Theorem available to you (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) you can apply it to $x^2-p$.