# Notation for an integer being square-free

Tags: notation

An integer $n \neq 0$ is square-free if $n$ is divisible by no prime square. Can you figure out any notation for simplifying this long description?

It may be guessed that $p^{2} \nmid n$ for any prime $p$ is okay, but this is still a bit long.

Comment: There is no standard notation. As for characterizations, besides $\,a^2\mid n\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid 1,\,$ there are [many others.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/54105/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we could use $\mu(n)\ne 0$. Here $\mu$ is the [Möbius function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) I prefer (by a lot) to say square-free.

Comment: Ah right! It is the Mobius function that I cannot recall.

Comment: Should be $\,\mu(n)\color{#c00}\neq 0\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: Thanks for catching it. This may be a personal record for error to length ratio.

Answer (score 1):

$n=ab$ implies $gcd(a,b)=1$ for all $a,b$.