# On P. Starni's "Some Extensions to Touchard's Theorem on Odd Perfect Numbers"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, terminology, divisibility, perfect-numbers

I am currently skimming through Paolo Starni's [Some Extensions to Touchard’s Theorem on
Odd Perfect Numbers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.05286.pdf).

I shall start citing from **Statement $1$** in page $1$:

> **Statement $1$** (Euler). If $n$ is an odd perfect number, then $n = \pi^{\alpha} M^2$, where $\pi$ is prime, $\gcd(\pi,M)=1$ and $\pi \equiv \alpha \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

> $\cdots$

On page $2$:

> **Note $1$** (factors of $n$ related to $\sigma(\pi^{\alpha})$).  We can find factors of $n$ considering that:
> $$n = \pi^{\alpha} M^2 = \dfrac{\sigma(\pi^{\alpha})}{2}\cdot\sigma(M^2)$$
> and
> $$\sigma(\pi^{\alpha}) = (\pi + 1)(1 + {\pi}^2 + + {\pi}^4 + \ldots + {\pi}^{\alpha - 1}).$$
> Since $\gcd(\pi^{\alpha},\sigma(\pi^{\alpha}))=1$, we have that $(\pi + 1)/2 \mid M^2$.  **In particular, if $(\pi + 1)/2$ is *squarefree*, then $\bigg((\pi + 1)/2\bigg)^2 \mid M^2$.**

My question is about the boldened portion as I have cited **Note $1$** from page $2$:

**QUESTION**

> Is it not the case that one should change the word *squarefree* to *prime* to make the implication mathematically correct?  Or is the implication with the word *squarefree* mathematically correct as it is?

**MY ATTEMPT**

For example, when $\pi = 5$, then $(\pi + 1)/2 = 3 \mid M^2$, which correctly implies that $\bigg((\pi + 1)/2\bigg)^2 = 3^2 = 9 \mid M^2$.

<s>I am, however, unable to come up with an example with prime $\pi \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and squarefree but non-prime $(\pi + 1)/2$.</s>

For an example of a prime $\pi \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ with squarefree but non-prime $(\pi + 1)/2$, just take $\pi = 29$, where $(\pi + 1)/2 = 15$.

**I am therefore highly doubtful about the mathematical accuracy of using *squarefree* instead of *prime* in the implication indicated in the boldened portion above.**

Comment: Please feel free to remove the **[soft-question]** tag if you think that it is not appropriate.

Comment: If $a$ is squarefree with $a\mid b^2$, then we have $a\mid b$ which implies $a^2\mid b^2$. I have not been able to find an exact duplicate of your question, but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1848177/78967) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54105/78967) do answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  Kindly post your last comment as an actual answer so that I could upvote then accept.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is squarefree with $a\mid b^2$, then we have $a\mid b$ which implies $a^2\mid b^2$.

I have not been able to find an exact duplicate of your question, but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1848177/78967) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54105/78967) do answer your question.