# Name of integers whose prime factorization is exponent free [squarefree]

Tags: terminology, definition, prime-factorization

Let $n > 1$ be a positive integer. Suppose that $n$ is a product of distinct primes
$$n= \prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{\alpha_i}$$ i.e. $\alpha_i=1$ for every $i$. Said equivalently: $\,n\,$ has no repeated (square) factor.

Surely if $n=pq$ we call them semiprimes but beyond that do we have a general term? Would you just say that $n$ is a "product of distinct primes"

The motivation here is simple. I noticed that the numbers of the form $${2^n \choose 2}^n+1$$ appear to be exponent free in thier prime factorization up to  $n=12$ using GAP.

---

Update 2021: The first value $n$ for which ${2^n \choose 2}^n+1$ is not squarefree is 15.
\begin{align}
{2^{15} \choose 2}^{15}+1=3^3×11×19×251×331×4051×18837001×4714696801×1133836730401×281941472953710177758647201
\end{align}

Comment: Square-free? $\text{ }$

Comment: yep thanks [square-free](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squarefree.html)

Comment: Note that $1$ is included in the square-frees.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54105/242) for many characterizations of squarefree integers (which can also be used as definitions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such numbers are called *square-free integers*, see for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer). A way to express the fact that $n$ is square-free is to write $\mu(n) \neq 0$, where $\mu$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).

I have no idea about your particular problem. I know that it was only proved recently (1996) that ${2n \choose n} $ is never square-free for $n \geq 5$… ! Notice that your numbers are just $x(n) = 1+(2^{n-1} (2^n-1))^n$.

Comment: Do you mean to say ${2n \choose n} $ is never square free for $n>4$ [Erdos Square Free Conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ErdosSquarefreeConjecture.html)

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez: yes sorry… I was a bit hasty ;-)