# What is the problem here (all integers are irrational proof...I think so)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fake-proofs

Let us assume $a$ is an integer which is rational which implies $a=p/q$ (where $p$ and $q$ are integers and $q$ not equal to $0$). If $p$ and $q$ are not coprime, let us simplify the fraction so this it is (I don't know how to talk like mathematicians).

Which implies, $$a=b/c$$ (where $b$ and $c$ are coprime integers). Squaring on both sides,
\begin{align}
a^2&=b^2/c^2\\
a^2c^2&=b^2
\end{align}
So $a^2$ is a factor of $b^2$, and also of $b$, due to the uniqueness of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.
So,
\begin{align}
b &=a^{2}d   \tag{where $d$ is an integer}\\
b^2 &= a^{4}d^{2}
\end{align}
But $b^2=a^2c^2$ So,
\begin{align}
a^2c^2 &= a^4d^2\\
c^2 &= a^2d^2
\end{align}

So, $a^2$ is a factor of $c^2$ and $c$ due to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. So $b$ and $c$ have $a^2$ as a common factor. But this contradicts the fact that $b$ and $c$ are coprime. This is because we have taken $a$ as a rational integer, so $a$ cannot be a rational integer.

What's wrong here (genuinely asking)?

Comment: "a^2 is a factor b^2 and b" You are right $a^2$ divides $b^2$, but why would it divide $b$?

Comment: First error I spotted is that $a^2$ need not be a factor of $b$ just because it is a factor of $b^2$. Indeed, if $a=2$ and $b=2$, then $a^2=4$ is a factor of $b^2=4$ but $a^2=4$ is not a factor of $b=2$.

Comment: Also, it is clear that integers are rational because given any integer $a$ we can write $a=\frac{a}{1}$.

Comment: You should probably check out https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to help you format your future posts. For example, it's hard to read "This is because we have taken a as a rational integer so a cannot be a rational integer" as opposed to "This is because we have taken $a$ as a rational integer so $a$ cannot be a rational integer".

Comment: In the time of typing this, could you not have gone through an example like $a=2 = 2/1$ and noticed that $2^2$ being a factor of $2^2$ does not imply that $2^2$ is a factor of $2$? Genuinely asking.

Comment: "Also, it is clear that integers are rational because ...."  That does not answer the question "what is wrong with this proof"?  It's obvious that integers are rational.  But the OP has a proof that they are not.  So the proof must be wrong.  So the OP is guenuinely asking where the error is.  Pointing out that integers are obviously rational does nothing to answer that.

Comment: If b and c are coprime, and a=b/c, then what does c have to be?

Comment: @Toolazytothinkofaname It is rather simple to spot the error. Substitute the variables by actual integers and find where the proof is wrong.

Answer (score 44):

The problem in the proof is that $a^2|b^2\nRightarrow a^2|b$. For instance, take $a=2$ and $b=6$. Clearly, $4|36$ but $4\nmid 6$.

Comment: The symbol $|$  what means ?

Comment: @EduardoS. $a\mid b$ means that "$a$ divides $b$" i.e., there exists an integer $k$ such that $b=ak$ with $a\ne 0$.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are confusing that if $p$ is prime and $p$ divides $b^k$ then $p|b$.  That is true if $p$ is prime.

Actually it's also true for a composite $a|b^k$ then $a|b$ if $a$ has no square factors.  But if $a$ as any prime factors to a power greater than $1$ it need not be true.

And in fact its obviously *not* true as $a^2$ divides $a^2$ but $a^2$ doesn't divide $a$ (unless $a = 1$).

Read on....

It most certainly is not true if $a|b^k$ that $a|b$   It means that the prime factors of $a$ are prime factors of $b$.  And it means that the powers of those prime factors of $a$ are at most equal to $k$ times the powers of the same prime factors of $b$ but because $k$ is larger than .....

Oh let me put it this way.

Suppose $a = \prod p_i^{m_i}$ be the prime factorization of $a$.  Suppose $a|b^k$.  Then that means that $p_i$ are prime factors of $b$ and that $b = d\prod p_i^{j_i}$.  And it means that $b^k = d^k \prod p_i^{k*j_i}$.

And as $a|b^k$ that means each $m_i \le k*j_i$.  But that does *not* mean $m_i \le j_i$ which would mean $a|b$.

You statement $a|b^k$ means $a|b$ if $a$ has square free and all the prime factor powers were $1$ but not other wise.

Simple example if $a = 12 = 2^2*3$ and $b= 90 = 2*3^2*5$.  Now $a|b^2 = 8100 = 2^2*3^4*5^2$.

This means the prime factors of $a$ ($2,3$) are also prime factors of $b$.  And it means that the powers of the prime factors of $a$  ($2\mapsto 2; 3\mapsto 1$) are less or equal to $2$ times the powers in $b$  ($2\mapsto 1$ and $2 \le 2*1$ and $3\mapsto 2$ and $1 \le 2*2$) but it doesnt mean the are less than or equal to the powers of $b$.  (In $a; 2\mapsto 2$ but in $b; 2\mapsto 1$ and $2 \not \le 1$).

So $12 \not \mid 90$.

It's certainly can't be the case that $a|b \implies a^2| b^2 \implies a^2|b$!  That would mean every time you have $a|b$ you can just keep squaring and reducing to get $a^{m}|b$ for *any* power of $m$.

That would mean if $3|6$ then $3^2|6$ and $3^4|6$ and $3^{2048}|6$ and so on.

Or in this case as $a = b$ (and $c=1$.... because $a$ is an integer) you would have $a|a$ so $a^2|a$?  And $a^4|a$.  That's .... simply not true.

Comment: No, $\,p\mid b^k\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid b\,$ is true [$\iff p\,$ is *squarefree*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54105/242). Follow the link for a handful of characterizations of squarefree integers.

Comment: Why do you say "no"?  That is *exactly* what I said.

Comment: Because the first paragraph was incorrect. Now it is correct after your edit.

Comment: Okay.  I used "only" colloquially.  My bad.  I'm pretty sure the OP was confusing the FTA with Euclid's lemma.  So I said that only works if $p$ is prime.  Colloquially that doesn't mean $p$ being prime is required and it is false otherwise. It means you can only cite that lemma if $p$ is prime. There are many other ways $a|b^k$ and $a|b$ can both be true but citing Euclid's lemma is usually reserved for $a$ prime. But in math I shouldn't have used the loaded word "only".

Answer (score 2):

Basic facts missing  $ac=b$ is a lot easier to use.  $a^2$ does not need to divide $b$. A fraction sharing  no common factor other than 1, between the number on top ( numerator), and the number on the bottom ( denominator), is said to be in **lowest terms** .

Anyways starting from $a={b\over c}$ we get $ac=b$ showing c divides b, sharing no factor other than 1, and therefore, $c=1$, implying $a=b$ so $a={a\over 1}$ it Also can be used to show :$a={-a\over -1}$