# There do not exist positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that $5m + 3n^2 = 15.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

There do not exist positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that $$5m + 3n^2 = 15. $$

Comment: Is n2 supposed to be $n^2$?

Comment: Are you trying to type $5m+3n^2=15$?  If $m,n>0$ then there really aren't very many things to check.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: It's a variation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464749/when-does-p2-divide-ank-bp) result.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the integers must be *POSITIVE* then if $m \ge 3$ then $5m \ge 15$ and $5m + 3n^2 > 15$.

So $m = 1$ or $2$.

And if $n \ge 3$ then $5m + 3n^2 > 27 >15$ so $n=1$ or $2$.

So there are only four cases and none of them work.

Are you sure that the weren't supposed to be no integers at all (which isn't true as $n=0$ and $m=3$ is a solution.

Are maybe the question is suppose to be that there is no integers $m,n$ so that $5m^2 + 3n^2 = 15$.

As $3$ and $5$ divide $15$ and $5$ divides $5m^2$ we'd have $5$ must divide $3n^2$.  Which means.....?

And as $3$ divides $5m^2$ which means.....?