# $x^2\not \equiv 0 \pmod{165}$ for $0<x<165$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, self-learning

So I have this question that goes like this:

Show that $x^2\not \equiv 0 \pmod {165}$ for $0<x<165$. I think I have a solution, but I'm not quite sure if it's correct:

if $x^2\equiv 0 \pmod{165}$ then
$$x^2\equiv 0 \pmod{3},\ x^2\equiv 0 \pmod{5},\ x^2\equiv 0 \pmod{11},$$
but if this is true then
$$x\equiv 0 \pmod{3},\ x\equiv 0 \pmod{5},\ x\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$$
and then CRT gives that
$$x\equiv 0 \pmod{165},$$
but for $x\in \{ 1,...,164\}$ this cannot be true.

Is this correct? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You want to use `\pmod{...}` to get mod in parentheses.

Comment: Looks perfect to me.

Comment: [Generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54105/242) $\, n\,$ is squarefree $ \iff\ [\,n\mid x^2\Rightarrow\, n\mid x\,]\ $ (or $\bmod n\!:\ x\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, x^2\not\equiv 0,\,$ equivalently), so this property characterizes *squarefree* integers. Follow the link for many more such characterizations.

Answer (score 2):

Notation questions aside, the math is good.  A similar argument applies using any square-free natural number (such as $165=3×5×11$) as the modulus.